# Cart 22 does not contain item 30

Tags: magento2

[image]How can i add item in magento 2 cart without login ?

Comment: you can add product in cart by default in magento without login. There is no need to login for add product in cart.

Comment: i tried but i got this error message ..Cart 22 does not contain item 30

Comment: @ShyamHajare - check if anything missing in checkout_cart_product_add_after event function, because above mentioned error is mostly occurred on save of item into quote. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Please see patch here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/1fb3a97b4f394ae05d7afc5a213d0eb22d6e7c2e)

this bug already resolved updated in latest versions

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add same product in cart programmatically then you must have to specify any one field value different then other same product in quote item table. E.g. you can use description field to store any unique data for same types of products